# php not converting dates

Tags: php, date

This might be very simple, but I still need help with this.

I have this portion of php code:

```
$END = NULL;

if (isset ($_POST['end'])){
    $END = date_format($_POST['end'], "Y-m-d H:i");
}
```

Where `$_POST['end']` is a date and time that I get in format `dd-mm-YYYY HH:mm`. The problem is, as you can guess, that it doesn't transform my input to the `Y-m-d H:i` format, it just doesn't do anything. But I've followed what I've seen in another code that does indeed work. What am I doing wrong here?

Ignore the fact that I don't check if the input is well written, I assume that it will be.

Comment: Did you look at what `date_format` does and expects as input exactly? http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.format.php

Comment: Yes I did, but after looking again I've noticed my mistake. Nevermind this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because date_format accepts an object and not a string. You should use the function [date](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) and pass to it's second argument a timestamp.

Answer (score 0):

Use date_create() function to convert string to date and then pass it to date_format() function.

```
if (isset ($_POST['end'])){
    $date = create_date( $_POST['end'] );
    $END = date_format($date, "Y-m-d H:i");
}
```